# How do I fix a bone mess from an import?

Tags: armature

I have this mess of a armature from an imported character with more bones and weight layer I won't redo. Shuld I just make a new one and copy the XYZ posision of the old ones or do it exist a better sulution.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Bones look fine, do they deform the mesh, are they weight painted?

Comment: They work but are horibel to work with becus it is hard to se what they ar doing

Comment: you can move bones to other layers, by selecting the ones you dont need and press "m" and move them to another layer

Comment: If they are named correctly, you can use "select similar prefix" in armature edit mode. Was this imported from another blender file?

Comment: No. A .bfx and the pose was usles so the firs thing was to reset it

Comment: select a non deformation bone, press space, type "select similar prefix or suffix" if they were named right, it will automatically select all the master bones, the ones that control all the others. Or you can select a bone you dont want, press "L" and it will auto select all bones that are linked to it, then you can move them to another layer. Master bones arent usually linked to any other bones.

Comment: @AlfonsMarklén why don't you select the armature and press H to hide?

Comment: I have used Ctrl+P to connect the bones and did start to try to rotate them so they make sens. hands is actually recognisable now.